# View plist raw xml in monodevelop

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, plist, monodevelop

I really need to see the xml of the plist in monodevelop or in xcode.

Currently the plist file doesn't appear in xcode only in monodevelop and i cant find a way to edit the xml directly.

As a general rant monodev is great but why have this gui editing of xml at all when probably one key reason why people are avoiding xcode is because of its insistence of this obfuscation.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: I agree.  Monodevelop should have an option to "Open With/Source Code Editor" for these files.  Three are many behaviors you can customize in Monodeveop.  I did not find a way to do it.

Comment: Note that plist files are not guaranteed to be XML; they can also be a binary format.

Answer (score 2):

It *might* work depending on what software you have installed.

E.g. from MonoDevelop I can right click on my `Info.plist`, select **Open With** and choose Dashcode.app.

This works (for me) because I still have my old Xcode 4.2 installed (on OSX Lion) and that ships with dashcode as a separate .app.

AFAIK MonoDevelop queries the operating system for any application that can open `.plist` files. So if you have an application that can read them (or XML) you *should* be able to create this association (using Finder) and have MonoDevelop open it.

Anyway you should fill a bug report (enhancement) on MonoDevelop so it can open those `.plist` files using it's own XML editor.